# Use custom image icons in ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting

I would like to do an `ArrayPlot` where, instead of using colors, I can place my own custom images.

I tried something like `ArrayPlot[{0,1,0,1}, ColorRules->{0->img1, 1->img2}]`, but it looks like some sort of average of the image is taken, which is then used as the color.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GraphicsGrid`:

```
{img1, img2} = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Mandrill"};
GraphicsGrid[RandomInteger[1, {5, 5}] /. {0 -> img1, 1 -> img2},  Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Or replace array entries with `ImageData` of input images, `ArrayFlatten` the resulting nested array and use `Image` on the result:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[1, {5, 5}];
Image[ArrayFlatten[mat /. {0 -> ImageData[img1], 1 -> ImageData[img2]}]] // 
 ImageResize[#, 300] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Multicolumn`

```
{img1, img2} = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Mandrill"};
Multicolumn[RandomInteger[1, 16] /. {0 -> img1, 1 -> img2}, 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]